# Json Load - ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json

Trying to load a file with json string, below is my code, it's working fine with other files but only issue with this file. checked in json lint also, no issues json string is valid.i tried all the solutions for other similar kind of questions but no luck

```
from jsonkeyvalue import find
import json
from xlutils.copy import copy 
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import easyxf

rb = open_workbook('Login_updated.xls',formatting_info=True)
r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(1)
wb = copy(rb)
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(1)

module  = ['Login','Dashboard']
keyword = ['getText']



with open('data_french.json') as data_file:    
  j = json.load(data_file)






for row in range(r_sheet.nrows):    
  if((r_sheet.cell(row,0).value in module) & (r_sheet.cell(row,3).value in keyword)):
    w_sheet.write(row,13, str(find(r_sheet.cell(row,4).value,j)))


wb.save("Login_updated.xls")
```

Error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vbabu\Desktop\Resource Bundle\getvaluefrmjson.py", line 18, in <module>
    j = json.load(data_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

JSON Sample:

```
{
    "app": {
        "Flower": {
            "label": {
                "red_flower": "Nite queen",
                "white_flower": "grce reward",
                "green_flower": "Marigold",
                "yellow_flower": "jasmine",
                "blue_flower": "shoe flower",
                "maroon_flower": "marigold"
            }
        },
        "title": {
            "initialLabel": "dl",
            "policyLabel": "pq",
            "advertiseLabel": "cp",
            "granitePage": "grace",
            "positonPage": "MuskVan",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever you have in `data_french.json` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Please show the contents of the file, it must be something within it. If it's french, does it contain by any chance non-ascii characters? Remember these need to be encoded properly, and the encoding must be passed to the loads-call if it's not utf-8.

Comment: it's a valid json, lint doesn't show any error. yes it does contain non-ascii charcters

Comment: If it's an encoding error it wouldn't give `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`. Either way post your json file.

Answer (score 3):

Invalid json, you have an extra comma on the following line

```
"positonPage": "MuskVan",//here
```